# Why is GTM merging object values in dataLayer?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have the following code:

```
  dataLayer.push({event: 'A',eventAttributes: { attrA: 'a' }});
  dataLayer.push({event: 'B',eventAttributes: { attrB: 'b' }});
  dataLayer.push({event: 'C',eventAttributes: { attrC: 'c' }});
```

and a completely empty GTM container (no tags, no triggers, no variables).

When I inspect the `Data Layer` tab of the GTM debug, I see this:

```
{
  gtm: {start: 1448552543040, uniqueEventId: 1448552543091},
  event: 'A',
  eventAttributes: {attrA: 'a'}
}

{
  gtm: {start: 1448552543040, uniqueEventId: 1448552543092},
  event: 'B',
  eventAttributes: {attrA: 'a', attrB: 'b'}
}

{
  gtm: {start: 1448552543040, uniqueEventId: 1448552543092},
  event: 'C',
  eventAttributes: {attrA: 'a', attrB: 'b', attrC: 'C'}
}
```

As you can see GTM is merging values to the `eventAttributes` object instead of overwriting the object.

**Q1: Why is GTM doing this?**

**Q2: Is there a way I can prevent this from happening (apart from defining each object property as a separate variable)?**

FYI I'm using the `eventAttributes` object in the Data Layer because I want to then simply re-use whatever is in it as attributes for my event-based tools (Mixpanel, KISSmetrics...). With the above issue, I just don't see any way to scale GTM implementations for Mixpanel/KISSmetrics if I have to explicitly declare all variables in the DataLayer and GTM.

**UPDATE**

After reviewing the dataLayer in the console itself, it appears the values are properly pushed and not merged:

[image]

So it must be when reading the dataLayer that GTM decides to merge them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer to Q1:**

GTM is doing this because this is the behaviour of the DataLayer as intended:
https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper

[image]

*Adding Q2 answer from **Kitravee Siwatkittisuk** to make this post exhaustive:*

**Answer to Q2:**
*Thanks to Kitravee Siwatkittisuk*

set _clear to true [to preventing default recursive merge](https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper#preventing-default-recursive-merge)

```
dataLayer.push({items: [1], _clear: true})
```

Comment: It's truly utterly insane that the **default** behavior is to merge arrays. I am using GA4 where I send product impressions (so that may be a dozen products on a page). But when I send the purchase information (items) with an array of ONE product it merges them and reports that the customer bought a dozen items! Insane. Adding `_clear: true` fixed it.

Comment: In order to avoid possible confusion I wanted to add that I'm not explicitly installing the data layer helper referenced in this answer. I use GTM and manually run `window['dataLayer'].push(...)` to push my data (and then my tags act on it). The built-in data layer functionality **does** support `_clear: true` and you don't need to install the helper to be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to Q2:**

set _clear to true [to preventing default recursive merge](https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper#preventing-default-recursive-merge)

```
dataLayer.push({items: [1], _clear: true})
```